# Running a Jenkins Task interacting with GUI (Foreground)

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having trouble running a Python code that interacts with a Windows program through the GUI using Jenkins on a Windows 10 virtual machine. I want Jenkins to run a task triggered for example by an email and then execute my code. The reason I'm running Jenkins in a virtual machine instead of a server is that part of my process involves opening a program that can only be used on Windows and Mac.

When I'm in the virtual machine, I navigate to the folder where my code is located, let's say `cd D:\Users\my_user\my_folder`, and then run my code with poetry using `poetry run python3 main.py`, which executes my code correctly. My code enters a program that is installed in the virtual machine and retrieves some information that I need for subsequent processes.

The problem is that when I run the code on Jenkins, it runs in the background, and from what I understand of Jenkins' functioning, it creates an instance where it replicates the working environment that I need and runs the entire process in that instance. However, I never manage to get it to interact with the Windows 10 GUI, so it never interacts with the program.

The way I run Jenkins is as follows: I create a task called "My Task", add the trigger that I consider necessary, and in the Build Steps section, I select the option "Execute Windows command". My action in that cmd is very simple, I do exactly the same as I do manually, that is, `cd D:\Users\my_user\my_folder` and `poetry run python3 main.py`. With this configuration, Jenkins effectively enters the directory, identifies poetry and tries to run the Python code. My logs run correctly, the timeouts, etc., but since it never manages to interact in the foreground or upfront, it never actually interacts with the GUI cmd or opens the program (because I assume that in the backgorund instance Jenkins creates, that program doesn't exist as such).

I asked ChatGPT about this, not caring that the last version of Jenkins it knows is `version 2.303.1`, and it mentioned the xvnc plugin, but its functioning is not what I expect. In fact, I'm still not very clear about what xvnc does exactly. Here is the [Xvnc plugin documentation page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/xvnc/)

In addition, I searched for a plugin that specifically says "Windows". The only one I found is this plugin called "Windows Exe Runner", here is the [Windows Exe Runner plugin documentation page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/windows-exe-runner/), but it doesn't explain much. Still, on my local Jenkins I saved a Windows Exe called "CMD", whose default value is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

So basically, that's my problem. I'm a little desperate because I can't find a way to interact with the Windows GUI automatically. Thank you very much.